# Touchpad not working on Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have a Lenovo laptop with Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows 10 for almost a year and a half now, initially, the touchpad worked fine but one day it stopped working. However, my wireless USB mouse is working fine and even the touchpad is working in Windows 10. My xinput looks like this

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo 300 Wireless Compact Mouse Lenovo 300 Wireless Compact Mouse   id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3336-001                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo 300 Wireless Compact Mouse Lenovo 300 Wireless Compact Mouse   id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I don't  know what is the problem and how to fix it. I tried updating grub and reinstalling synaptics driver but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798  (regression fix (kernel -73) is currently in proposed repo, expected to hit 'main' on 7-jan-2020; use an old kernel or enable proposed repo)

Comment: I tried looking for the kernel version and it is showing 4.15.0-72-generic

Comment: Yep, and as I indicated (*in my strange way last comment, really comment #13 in given bug report*) 4.15.0-73 contains the fix currently in proposed (testing), expected to hit...   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get it now

Comment: I updated the kernel to the current latest version (-76) but still, it isn't working and now it is not even showing on the xinput list